# Is it okay to pray the Taraweeh prayers at home?

Tags: practical-islam, source-identification, ramadan, taraweeh

This question is about the `taraweeh` prayers during `Ramadan`. My question is *not* about 8 or 20 rak'ahs; rather I wanted to know if it is ok to pray `taraweeh` prayers at home.

Is it ok if I pray the `taraweeh` prayers alone at home after completing the `Eesha` salaah by congregation in the Masjid? For years I have been trying to get an answer to this, but have got different opinions from different folks. I would be grateful if the answer is based on the authentic hadeeth and the actions of the Sahaabaah (RAA).

Comment: Assalam Alaikum, i would like to suggest you split your questions up into separate questions.  I would suggest that question number 1, should be a one whole (new) question.  as for your 3rd question I suggest you make it a new question, asking whether it is ok to recite short Surahs in the night prayer or not.  As for the rest of the question, +1, great question :)

Comment: Waleikum Assalaam. Done!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is ok to do Taraweeh at your house, for the Prophet (peace and blessings be upon him) did not do it all the time in Jama'ah (for fear it may become Fardh).

For further information [see this (Arabic)](http://islamqa.info/ar/ref/38922). and here is the [translated version in (English)](http://islamqa.info/en/ref/38922)

Comment: from the hadiths it seems that doing it alone is more closer to Sunnah and prefered then setting up a congregation.

Comment: @Ali doing it congregation is still very good, and we can do it, for the fear of it becoming Fard is non-existent anymore.

Comment: But upto the time of Hazrat Umar RA it was not even practiced?

Comment: A good explanation on why Umar RA gather the people to pray Tarawih behind a single imam can be found here: https://islamqa.info/en/65572